# How to let WkWebview support js module feature? use require.js?

Tags: javascript, wkwebview, ecmascript-5, es6-module-loader

I need to let WkWebview to read my .ts file, which include "export" and "import". after I compile to js,  it seems that WkWebView does not support the js module, which could not read my function. Is there any way to check which of js features(especially  es6) support? also if I use requires.js could this problem be solved?